# std::initializer_list to return member variables returns incorrect values

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Is there any issue with returning the multiple values from function using `std::initializer_list`. In following code when I try to print the values returned using `std::initializer_list`,  I am getting junk values.

**header file**

```
#ifndef _C17_CONSTRUCT_3_HPP
#define _C17_CONSTRUCT_3_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

class A {
    public:
        A(int a,int b):a{a},b{b}{}
        std::initializer_list<int> return_init_list()
        {
            std::initializer_list<int> local_list = {a, b};
            std::cout<<"a "<<a<<" b "<<b<<std::endl;
            return local_list;
        }
    private:
        int a{9};
        int b{10};
};
#endif
```

**Source file**

```
#include "c17_construct_3.hpp"

int main()
{
    A a{9, 10};
    std::initializer_list<int> ret = a.return_init_list();
    std::cout<<"ret list size "<<ret.size()<<std::endl;

    for(auto list_elem : ret)
        std::cout<<list_elem<<std::endl;
}
```

### **Output**

```
a 9 b 10  
ret list size 2  
-1489302992  
32692
```

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use std::initiallizer_list here? Your program actually runs just fine for me.

Comment: `_C17_CONSTRUCT_3_HPP` is reserved.

Comment: @Cruiser not a requirement . I was just checking the usage of std::initializer_list. What is the compiler & version used by you ? Mine  g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` is not a container, you cannot use it to return a list of items from a function. When you write the following

```
std::initializer_list<int> local_list = {a, b};
```

the compiler translates that into code functionally similar to the following

```
const int __temp_array[2] = {a, b};
std::initializer_list<int> local_list{__temp_array, __temp_array + 2};  
// the above line assumes the implementation has access to such a constructor
```

An almost identical example can be found in the standard - *§8.5.4/5 [dcl.init.list]*

In your code the temporary array containing copies of `a` and `b` ceases to exist when the function `return_init_list()` returns. Use `std::pair` or `std::tuple` to return the values.

Comment: is it &a or &temp_array

Comment: @uknowit It's `__temp_array`, finally fixed all the screw ups :)